# Django, Python 3.4, CentOS 6.4, virtualenv: ImportError: No module named Django

Tags: python, django, pip

I am running a Linux server with CentOS 6.4. I need to run Django 1.8.2 with Python 3.4. I already have pip and virtualenv installed, and I am currently in a virtual env. I tried to install Django using the pip command but it has installed it in the Python 2.6 site packages, so when I run a python 3 interpreter and type `import django` I get `ImportError: No module named Django`. I need to find a way to install Django with Python 3.4. I do not have pip3 and cannot figure out how to install it. All of the help I have found on other sites deals with Ubuntu systems and do not work for me.

EDIT:

`which pip` outputs `~/MAP_VIO/bin/pip`
`which python3` outputs `/usr/local/bin/python3`
`which python` outputs `~/MAP_VIO/bin/python`

MAP_VIO is my virtual env, so it looks like I don't have python 3 in my virtual env? If that's my problem, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you installed a Python 2 virtual environment.  To get a Python 3 environment you need to do

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv_path
```

The `-p` flag tells it which interpreter you want.  That should install both pip3 and setuptools into the environment.  If you really don't have pip3 (which virtualenv can copy into the environment) and can't install it system wide for some reason, try doing

```
easy_install pip
```

inside the virtual environment.  That should be able to fetch and install the right pip for the virtual environment you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Please see that you are using the correct, virtualenv'ed, `pip` command.

You can verify this by running command:

```
  which pip
```

... and it will tell you the absolute path of pip command (and Python installation) you are using.

Also do the same for `python` command you are trying to run Django with. If necessary edit your question and add the relevant information about virtualenv, python and pip paths.

Comment: My question has been changed to reflect this.